# XSl:Variable - Condition to check whether value exist

Tags: xslt

Using XSLT 1.0, how do I check whether the value in the variable exists or not?

I am assigning the value to the variable initially from my XML data and then need to check whether it exits or not:

```
<xsl:variable name="DOC_TYPE">
  <xsl:value-of select="name(./RootTag/*[1])"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:if test="string($DOC_TYPE) = ''">
  <xsl:variable name="DOC_TYPE">
    <xsl:value-of select="name(./*[1])"/>
  </xsl:variable>
</xsl:if>
```

The above is not working as expected. What I need is if `<RootTag>` exists in my data then the variable should contain the child node below the `<RootTag>`. If `<RootTag>` does not exist then the DOC_TYPE should be the first Tag in my XML data.

Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 9):

You can't re-assign variables in XSLT. Variables a immutable, you can't change their value. Ever.

This means you must decide *within* the variable declaration what value it is going to have:

```
<xsl:variable name="DOC_TYPE">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="RootTag">
      <xsl:value-of select="name(RootTag/*[1])" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="name(*[1])" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

A few other notes:

- this: `'./RootTag'` is redundant. Every XPath you don't start with a slash is relative by default, so saying `'RootTag'` is enough
- this: `<xsl:value-of select="name(*[1])"/>` already results in a string (names are strings by definition), so there is no need to do `<xsl:if test="string($DOC_TYPE) = ''">` , a simple `<xsl:if test="$DOC_TYPE = ''">` suffices
- to check if a node exists simply select it via XPath in a `test="..."` expression - any non-empty node-set evaluates to `true`
- XSLT has strict scoping rules. Variables are valid within their parent elements only. Your second variable (the one within the `<xsl:if>`) would go out of scope *immediately*(meaning right at the `</xsl:if>`).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try this way and let me know if I have an y question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
   <xsl:variable name="DOC_TYPE">
     <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="/RootTag"><xsl:value-of select="name(/RootTag/*[1])"></xsl:value-of></xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="name(/*[1])"/></xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:variable>
```

Answer (score 0):

It only exists if you have assigned it. There's no reason to test it for existence.

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299808/in-xslt-how-do-you-test-to-see-if-a-variable-exists/1299842#1299842)

Comment: Thanks. But My requirement is sometime I get data like this
<RootTag>
  <Order>
  </Order>
</RootTag>
Then I need the Variable name as Order. Sometime I get data like this mean without RootTag
<Order>
</Order>
Then also my variable should contain <order> value. How do I acheive this ?

Comment: In your example variable always exists, it's the content that may differ. But anyway, since Jim Garrison's suggestion seems to have worked for you, I believe you should accept his answer.